# How to sort a list of tuples which contain two integer element firstly by its second, then by its first element descending in Python?

Tags: python

I've been using loops in order to solve my problem but my brain has stopped. I have a input as a list which contains couple of tuples like this:

```
input_list = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 3), (7, 3), (4, 4)]
```

I would like to mix this tuples. Here are the steps:

1. Tuples have to be sorted in ascending by its second element for every time. ((X, **2**), (X, **3**), (X, **4**), (X, **2**), (X, **3**), (X, **2**))
2. First element of the tuple must be the smallest value. ((**1**, 2), (**5**, 3), (**4**, 4), (**2**, 2), (**7**, 3), (**3**, 2))

Here is the output I would like to achieve:

```
output_list = [(1, 2), (5, 3), (4, 4), (2, 2), (7, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Can someone help me to find the algorithm to mix and convert to input list to the output list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the input by the second, then the first element. For each tuple in the sorted list, iterate a list of "slots" (lists) and add the tuple to the first slot whose last item is less than the tuple. If there's no such slot, create a new slot. Finally, join the slots into one list:

```
slots = []

for p in sorted(INPUT, key=lambda p: p[::-1]):
    for s in slots:
        if s[-1][1] < p[1]:
            s.append(p)
            break
    else:
        slots.append([p])


result = sum(slots, [])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and keeping the answer so short! Your solution really enlightened me. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `roundrobin` from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). The function `group_values` sorts the data so that it can be used as an input for `roundrobin`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import cycle, islice


def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next_ in nexts:
                yield next_()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))


def group_values(data):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    # sort by the second element first
    for entry in sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])):
        result[entry[1]].append(entry)
    return result


def main():
    input_list = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 3), (7, 3), (4, 4)]
    grouped_lists = group_values(input_list)
    result = list(roundrobin(*grouped_lists.values()))
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`group_values` creates a dictionary that looks like this: `{2: [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)], 3: [(5, 3), (7, 3)], 4: [(4, 4)]}`. The function takes advantage of the fact that in modern versions of Python, entries in the dictionaries retain the order in which they were added.

The result is `[(1, 2), (5, 3), (4, 4), (2, 2), (7, 3), (3, 2)]`, even if you shuffle the input list.

You might want to use a debugger or add some `print` functions in the code if you want to see what's happening.

Comment: Thank you so much! Takes a little bit of time to understand for me but perfect explanation!